# Geometric Network for Electric Utilities?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geometric-network, utility-network-analyst

I'm not expert in the use of geometric networks nor in Python scripting and I need help with the following problem. I'm using ArcGIS 10.0.

I have defined a geometric network for an electric distribution network in medium and low voltage, with an own (basic) data model. The main feature classes included in the geometric network are Distribution Centers (points), Medium Voltage Feeders (lines), Substations (points), Low Voltage Cables (lines), Meters (points).

Each distribution center have several outputs with medium voltage feeders. Each substation has multiple outputs with low voltage cables, each with its own identifier.

I have to simulate outages in any parts of the network, identifying all affected users (meters). This part is pretty simple with "Utility Network Analyst" tools, with which I can select affected items in each feature class.

I have to pull attributes from multiple feature classes and combine them into a single table.The goal is to generate a table with the “connection diagram” of each meter, i.e. one record per meter affected by the outage with the following attributes: ID meter, ID low voltage cable, ID substation , medium voltage feeder ID, ID distribution center. Each attribute comes from a different feature class and I must build a table with corresponding values that indicate how each meter connects trough the network to each distribution center.

I think there is no way to accomplish this with the 'Utility Network Analyst' but perhaps there is a tool or some python script that can help me to solve the problem.

Either way I think that the solution is to create an own script. In an ESRI forum, very kind people recommended developing a bidirectional script (trace down and then up) using the CreateRow, Set_Value to generate the new row to insert into the connection diagram table and perform the required task.

Does anyone have examples on how to do this or starting point scripts?

Comment: I think you may need to use ArcObjects to do this. Or this might help you for a Python solution: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103109/automate-naming-of-stormwater-network-geometric-network